# XSD restriction pattern for accented characters

Tags: regex, xml, unicode, xsd

I working with XML/XSD files, but i have one problem with the validation.

One field has this restriction:

```
<xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9 '\-\./]+"/>
```

But when I put this value:

```
example with àccented character
```

The validator says that "The Pattern constraint failed"

So basically, what I'm asking is:  Are accented characters included in the a-z pattern?

If not, what can I do? (Consider that I'm not able to change the .xsd because it's not mine and I'm not allowed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, accented characters are not included in the `[A-Za-z]` pattern.

If you could change the XSD, and if you want a much more general Unicode-based pattern, you could specify:

```
<xs:pattern value="[\p{L}\p{P}\p{N}]+"/>
```

**Explanation**:

- \p{L} matches a letter
- \p{P} matches a punctuation character (to pick up your apostrophe
  request)
- \p{N} matches a number
- `[...]+` matches one or more of its containing characters.

If you cannot change the XSD, and if you wish for your document to be valid by it, you should abide by its constraints.  There could be reasons other than neglect that the XSD precludes non-ASCII code points.  For example, consuming applications may expect or even require ASCII there.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for editing my question (my english is not the best english you can read) and answering. I already checked your comment as answer.

Second, you're telling me that there is no way to put accented characters? Even with entities like &egrave; or something like that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `&egrave;` is an HTML entity that does not exist in plain XML, but yes, using the equivalent `&#xE8;` in an XML file would be no different from using `è` directly. The schema specifically disallows accented characters, so if you want to pass validation you will have to take them out.