# XML Schema (XSD) restriction pattern allowing only ISO 646 invariant subset (i.e. ASCII)?

Tags: regex, xml, validation, unicode, xsd

Can anyone see why my xsd restriction is not working?

**Update**: I tried the exact same xsd as below but in the regex I changed the `(` and `)` to `[` and `]`.

The version with square brackets works *perfectly* in the regex testers I tried **but** produces *a schema validation error in the XSD.* Yes, oXygen seems to be saying that a regex wrapped in `[]` is not allowed in an otherwise valid XSD.

So is it XML schema or oXygen that does not support the square-bracketed expression?

Or is it some other reason?

Related (?) question: [XSD restriction pattern for accented characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422061/xsd-restriction-pattern-for-accented-characters?rq=1)

The aim is to validate only strings conforming to the following 2 content models:

1. "tokenized":

`<xs:simpleType name="Tokenized500Type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="500"/>
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      <xs:pattern value="\S+( \S+)*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>`

and

2. (with the tokenization included as the base type) the ASCII character set:

`<xs:simpleType name="TransliteratedStringType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation> can only contain non-control characters drawn from the “invariant subset”
            of ISO 646 (i.e. ASCII). </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="example:Tokenized500Type">
        <xs:pattern
            value="(!|&quot;|%|&amp;|'|\(|\)|\*|\+|,|-|.|\/|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|:|;|&lt;|=|>|\?|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L| |M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|_|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)+"
        />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>`

I've tested the tokenization separately and it does seem to fit all the use cases it's meant for (removing any unneeded whitespace and restricting string length).

I can't figure out why the ASCII restriction is not working.

I thought perhaps some kind of mapping from characters with diacritics to the equivalent without, but turns out it's allowing other specially characters too, e.g. `ß`. Is it possible that `ß` is really mapped to `ss`? or `sz`?

Do I need to escape all the characters as unicode code points?

Or is there some kind of error in my use of `xs:restriction`?

Testing using:
 - oXygen XML Editor (regex inside XSD)
 - http://regexr.com/ (regex only)

Test strings:

`Dr. Bäcker`

`Dr. Baecker`

...and portions of:

`ŦŲƯY̨Ƴąɓçđɗęħįƙłøơşșţțŧųưy̨ƴÁÀÂÄǍĂĀÃÅǺĄÆǼǢƁĆĊĈČÇĎḌĐƊÐÉÈĖÊËĚ
ĔĒĘẸƎƏƐĠĜǦĞĢƔáàâäǎăāãåǻąæǽǣɓćċĉčçďḍđɗðéèėêëěĕēęẹǝəɛġĝǧğģɣĤḤĦIÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨĮỊĲĴĶƘĹĻŁĽĿʼNŃN̈ŇÑŅŊÓÒÔÖǑŎŌÕŐỌØǾ
ƠŒĥḥħıíìiîïǐĭīĩįịĳĵķƙĸĺļłľŀŉńn̈ňñņŋóòôöǒŏōõőọøǿơœŔŘŖŚŜŠŞȘṢẞŤŢṬŦÞÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨŰŮŲỤƯẂẀŴẄǷÝỲŶŸȲỸƳŹŻŽẒŕřŗſśŝšşșṣßťţṭŧþúùûüǔŭūũűůųụưẃẁŵẅƿýỳŷÿȳỹƴźżžẓ`

Comment: A couple of observations: The ASCII pattern is missing the space (&#20;) and you should not include a bare > (&gt;).
More importantly, it should be possible to represent the printable ASCII as "[&#x20;-&#x7E;]+".

Comment: I like that range, but please note that a basic issue appears to be `[]` versus `()` - see update above!

Comment: Hi @SMeyer - I tried escaping the space with &#x20; (I think you missed an x in your comment above?), but still getting the XSD validation error: InvalidRegex: Pattern value '([!|"|%|&|'|\(|\)|\*|\+|,|-|.|\/|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|:|;|<|=|>|\?|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L| |M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|_|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z])+' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This expression is not supported in the current option setting.'.

Comment: @SMeyer I don't think that spaces need to be escaped in XML, or is that a regex thing? Please see https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-predefined-ent for XML; the regex testers I've tried accepted the literal space.

Comment: There was a missing x, good catch. Yes, the space does not have to be escaped. Though it shouldn't hurt either. I just wanted to be clear which one I'm talking about.

Comment: Note that [] denotes a list of characters. On the other hand, () is a subexpression. As such, "(A|B|C)+" is equivalent to "[ABC]+". In your explicit list, there might be a character that should be escaped but isn't. Have you tried my range from the first comment?

Comment: If you propose one final answer I will test it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love to give the answer to the other poster here, but the unescaped `.` was only half the problem.

The `/` must not be escaped either, given I'm using an XML editor (as stated) based on Saxon, which throws an error for characters that *don't need* to be escaped.

Full answer here (off-SE): https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/topic13779.html#p40565

Comment: Adrian's answer is correct except that it suggests that disallowing "\/" is a Saxon quirk, which isn't the case - it's defined in the XSD 1.0 specification.

Comment: Yes, I guess it could read that way. Or it could read "because it's Saxon, you get the exact implementation of the XSD 1.0 spec, which disallows \/".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to restrict a string to the printable ASCII characters,
you can simply denote a Unicode range like this:

```
"[&#x20;-&#x7E;]+"
```

The range for [ISO-646](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646#Code_page_layout) is a bit more complicated, because it is not a continuous sequence:

```
"[&#x20;-&#x22;&#x25;-&#x3F;A-Z&#x5F;a-z]+"
```

In your explicit list of characters, you most likely are using an incorrectly escaped character, which causes the error.

Comment: Thanks!  I checked the list of escaped characters in XML, it's covered already in this expression.

The unicode range above seems to work so far.

Could you link to a reference where I can check that all the ISO 646 characters listed in the original regex (an no more) are covered by the range `&#x20;-&#x7E;`?

Comment: ...Maybe I left the `.` unescaped?

...Apparently also the schema validation engine (Saxon) doesn't like escaped `/`... and *this* was the XSD validation error

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that ISO-646 is different from the printable ASCII set. I added the range for that too.

Comment: I would still need to point to the documentation to verify the specific code range(s) though - the explicit regex is better because it's self-documenting

Comment: The link is included in the answer, i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646

Answer (score 1):

The error message from Saxon tells you exactly what is wrong:

```
Schema processing failed: Syntax error at char 31 in regular expression: Escape character '/' not allowed
```

That is to say, the rules for regular expressions in XSD 1.0 do not allow "/" (because "/" isn't special in regular expressions, it doesn't need to be escaped, and XSD doesn't allow characters to be escaped in these circumstances - this is a way of reserving them for future use).

Now I have some questions for you:

- Did you get this error message?
- If not, how were you running the validation?
- If you did get it, why did you ignore it?

Comment: No, I didn't get the message.

I think it got lost probably under some other errors; oXygen does that sometimes.

Had I gotten it, I sure wouldn't have ignored it! It's a perfect error message.

Thanks!